# rel -NoFollow- a categorias especificas

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cms

Muy buenas a todos, llevo años aterrizando en esta web cada vez que busco alguna duda y por fin he tenido la iniciativa de registrarme para poder realizar mi primera consulta.

Actualmente tengo una tienda Online con WooCommerce y en los archivos de las categorías me muestra un listado con imagen, titulo y nº de productos con el enlace a dicha subcategoría.

Me gustaría implementar alguna función en el functions.php donde especifíque las IDs de las categorías que quiera que tengan el enlace con el atributo **rel="nofollow"**, ya que son categorías sin texto y sin contenido que no quiero que sean indexadas por Google ni tampoco que sean seguidar por el Crawler de Google.

A las subcategorías se le llama en mi theme con la función **woocommerce_maybe_show_product_subcategories()**

Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hagas eso. Te explico el porque y lo que deberías hacer.

Poner un nofollow no quiere decir que no traspases el link juice o a la autoridad a esa página. El link juice o autoridad se transmitirá igualmente y al encontrarse Google un nofollow lo que pasará es que se perderá esa autoridad en el limbo.

Lo que debes hacer es poner el atributo noindex a las URLS que no quieres que se indexen para que Google no las muestre y luego, si quieres optimizar el crawl budget evitando que Google pierda tiempo en esas URLs, deberías poner las URLS con un Disallow en robots.txt. Cuando lo hayas hecho, revisa bien con Search Console que realmente Google no puede acceder y que si puede seguir accediendo al resto de URLS.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda,

Un saludo

Comment: Haré lo que dices, muchas gracias :)